# bash ADB shell sqlite3 script

Tags: android, bash, sqlite, shell, adb

I am having issues getting this simple bash script to work. Below is the simple script which I am trying to get to work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db "SELECT programs.title FROM programs"
```

I am getting the below error:

```sh
Error: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

If I run the command in terminal I get the correct output. I have also tried changing SELECT to select, and it is the same issue. Running manually in terminal as follows:

```sh
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db
sqlite> SELECT programs.title FROM programs;
*OUTPUT*
```

Gives the correct output.

Does anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong?

---

In regards to what @Jetchisel suggested, see below for what I tried with no success:

```sh
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db "SELECT programs.title FROM programs;"

adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db "SELECT programs.title FROM programs;";

adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db "SELECT programs.title FROM programs";
```

Comment: Your'e just missing a trailing semi colon `;`

Comment: @Jetchisel good catch, but I add the trailing semi colon but no luck. See question for revision for what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple fix, see below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db '"SELECT programs.title FROM programs;"'
```

Needed to add single quotes around the query.